# Sieve randomly assigns mails to folders

Tags: sieve-language

I'm using sieve rules like the following to sort logs from normal mails:

```
require ["fileinto", "envelope", "subaddress", "variables", "mailbox"];
# rule:[asdf-logs]
if anyof (address "From" "nagios@mail.com", address "From" "root@mail.com", address "To" "root@mail.com")
{
    fileinto "INBOX.asdf.logs";
}
# rule:[asdf]
if anyof (header :contains "Delivered-To" "my@mail.com", header :contains "cc" "asdf@mail.com", header :contains "to" "asdf@mail.com")
{
    fileinto "INBOX.asdf";
}
```

Now, if some mail is sent from `nagios@mail.com` to `my@mail.com`, the following two results are possible:

```
filing message into 'INBOX.asdf.logs'
filing message into 'INBOX.asdf'
```

My problem is that the mail will be sorted randomly into `asdf` or `asdf.logs`.
How can I solve this?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/566755/what-does-the-stop-command-in-dovecot-sieve-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the "[stop](https://thsmi.github.io/sieve-reference/en/control/core/stop.html)" command.

```
if anyof (address "From" "nagios@mail.com", address "From" "root@mail.com", address "To" "root@mail.com")
{
    fileinto "INBOX.asdf.logs";
    stop;
}
```

Most commands, including "fileinto", don't inherently stop processing. Further rules will be processed and matched unless you explicitly execute a "stop" command. In general, once you're sure you have a message filed where you want it to go, you probably want to run `stop;` so that no further portions of the sieve script are run.